# What's the difference between the WIN32 and _WIN32 defines in C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I know that `WIN32` denotes win32 compilation but what is `_WIN32` used for?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`WIN32` is a name that you could use and even define in your own code and so might clash with Microsoft's usage. `_WIN32` is a name that is reserved for the implementor (in this case Microsoft) because it begins with an underscore and an uppercase letter - you are not allowed to define reserved names in your own code, so there can be no clash.

Comment: When you say 'use' do you mean i could:
#define WIN32 12345
or:
#ifdef WIN32

Comment: by 'use' I mean `#ifdef` and `#define`.  `_WIN32` is meant to be used by any programming in the context of `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 92):

To elaborate (Neil Butterworth and blue.tuxedo have already given the correct answer):

- `WIN32` is defined by the SDK or the build environment, so it does not use the implementation reserved namespace
- `_WIN32` is defined by the **compiler** so it uses the underscore to place it in the implementation-reserved namespace

You'll find a similar set of dual defines with nearly identical names and similar uses such as `_UNICODE`/`UNICODE`, `_DEBUG`/`DEBUG`, or maybe `_DLL`/`DLL` (I think that only the UNICODE ones get much of any use in their different versions).  Though sometimes in  these cases (like `_UNICODE`), instead of the underscore version being defined *by* the compiler, they are used to control what the CRT headers do:

- `_UNICODE` tells the CRT headers that CRT names which can be either Unicode or ANSI (such as `_tcslen()` should map to the wide character variant (`wcslen()`)
- `UNICODE` does something similar for the SDK (maps Win32 APIs to their "`W`" variants)

Essentially the versions with the underscore are controlled by or used by the compiler team, the versions without the underscore are controlled/used by teams outside of the compiler.  Of course, there's probably going to be a lot overlap due to compatibility with past versions and just general mistakes by one team or the other.

I find it confusing as hell - and find that they are used nearly interchangeably in user code (usually, when you see one defined, you'll see the other defined in the same place, because if you need one you need the other).  Personally, I think that you should *use* the versions without the underscore (unless you're writing the compiler's runtime) and  make sure they both get defined (whether via hearers or compiler switches as appropriate) when you're defining one.

---

Note that the SDK will define `_WIN32` when building for the Mac because the compiler doesn't, kind of overstepping it's bounds. I'm not sure what projects use a Win32 API an a compiler targeting the Mac - maybe some version of Office for the Mac or something.

Comment: "I'm not sure what projects use a Win32 API an a compiler targeting the Mac - maybe some version of Office" - Office shares much code between platforms, including many Windows data types as internal currency, even when not running on Windows.

Answer (score 25):

WIN32 is a user-defined flag which may be required by some headers.
_WIN32 is automatically defined by the visual C/C++ compiler. Since it begins with an _ followed by a capital character, it is reserved by the implementation (meaning the C/C++ toolchain provider).

I prefer to use (read) _WIN32, seems safer to me.

Comment: I agree. To check if I am compiling on Windows, _WIN32 is reliable because it is always defined. WIN32 is only defined if I define it myself or include "Windows.h".

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: Use `_WIN32`, never `WIN32`.

`_WIN32` is automatically defined by the compiler, when you're compiling for Windows (even for x64).

`WIN32` is weird:

- It's defined in `<windows.h>`.
- MinGW also defines it automatically, but stops doing so if you use `-std=c++??` (as opposed to `-std=gnu++??`, which is the default).