# Is it possible to check whether you are building for 64-bit with Microsoft C Compiler?

Tags: c, windows, 64-bit, visual-c++

Is there a simple preprocessor macro that is defined for a 64-bit build? I thought `_WIN64` might have been it, but even when I build a 32-bit target, the parts enclosed in a `#ifdef _WIN64 ... #endif` are compiled in, and this is causing problems. It's Friday and I can't think straight, but I'm sure I'm overlooking something very simple here. Maybe even something involving `sizeof`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have always used _WIN64 to check if it is a 64 bit build.

N.B. _WIN32 is also always (automatically) defined by MSVC in 64 bit builds, so check for _WIN64 before you check for _WIN32:

```
#if defined( _WIN64 )

// Windows 64 bit code here

#elif defined( _WIN32 )

// Windows 32 bit code here

#else

// Non-Windows code here

#endif
```

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like your problem might be related to a header or project setting improperly defining `_WIN64` - that should be left to the compiler.

There's a subtle difference between `WIN64` and `_WIN64` (at least for the Microsoft compilers - other compilers should follow suit, but not all do):

- `_WIN64` is defined by the *compiler* when it's building a program for a Windows 64-bit platform. Note that this name is in the compiler implementor's namespace (leading underscore followed by a capital letter)
- `WIN64` is defined by the *Windows Platform SDK* (or whatever they're calling it this year) when targeting a 64-bit platform.

So if you're only including standard headers and don't take other measures to define it, `WIN64` will *not* be defined.

There's a similar story for `_WIN32` and `WIN32` - but checking other compilers: GCC 3.4.5 does define `WIN32` even if only standard headers are used. As does Digital Mars.

Microsoft's compilers and Comeau do not.

Another bit of (hopefully) well known trivia is that `_WIN32` and `WIN32` are set when targeting 64-bit Windows platforms.  Too much stuff would have broken otherwise.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662084/whats-the-difference-between-the-win32-and-win32-defines-in-c/662543#662543 for other trivia on names that differ by only a leading underscore.

Comment: "the Windows Platform SDK (or whatever they're calling it this year)" How I hate that constant renaming! +1

Comment: @MichaelBurr Where is `WIN64` defined? Could you (or anyone) point out the exact place? I searched for it across some versions of Platform SDKs and Visual Studio, but I did not find any `#define WIN64` at all! (It is _used_ in a couple of places, though, which therefore seems wrong...) Should `WIN64` be abandoned and always replaced by `_WIN64`?

Answer (score 8):

The Visual C++ compiler defines the following macros:

- _M_IX86 - x86 platform
- _M_IA64 - ia64 platform
- _M_X64 - x64 platform

Comment: However, `_WIN64`/`WIN64`/`_WIN32`/`WIN32` should almost always be used instead if Windows is the target - the defines you mention should be used only if you really need to deal with processor-specific differences (which should be rare) rather than differences in the OS platform (which are more common). If `_WIN64` is being improperly set in 32-bit builds, the problem should be fixed rather than skirted around.

Comment: The difference is that _WIN64, etc. macros are defined by you (or for you) in your project and the _M_X64, etc. macros are defined by the compiler.

Comment: Sorry, I take that back - compiler defines _WIN32 and _WIN64 as well as the processor specific ones.

Comment: These macros are useful when you want to differentiate between different 64-bit platforms like Itanium and Amd64 (maybe even ARM in the future), which you cannot do with just _WIN64. But the downside is, these compiler-defined macros are not available for use from within RC (resource) files, which are compiled using the resource compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Check your project's build properties, particularly the preprocessor section. Are you defining `_WIN64` somewhere in `WIN32` builds? The `sizeof` thing probably won't work since you cannot use in a `#if` test.

Comment: The `sizeof` thing won't work for preprocessor commands, but an `if` statement that has a compile-time constant should be optimised out (i.e. `if (sizeof(long) == 4)`. I remember seeing this in GNU's implementation of `strlen`. The code only executes once or twice, so performance is not important.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say, performance in my particular case is not important.