# Conditional compilation for different versions of Windows

Tags: visual-c++

Hello could anyone give me an example showing how do we use conditional compilation for different versions of operating system?
for example I want a program that works depending on the version win32 or win64 or on other platform

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to check whether you are building for 64-bit with Microsoft C Compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647930/is-it-possible-to-check-whether-you-are-building-for-64-bit-with-microsoft-c-com)

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking, I think he wants to know how to tell the windows headers "This is for OS version X"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is explained [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#setting_winver_or__win32_winnt). Basically, you #define `WINVER` to indicate the target operating system.

This is the relevant part of that page:

> **Setting WINVER or _WIN32_WINNT**
>
> You can define these symbols by using the #define statement in each
>   source file, or by specifying the /D compiler option supported by
>   Visual C++.
>
> For example, to set `WINVER` in your source file, use the following
>   statement:
>
> ```
> #define WINVER 0x0502
> ```
>
> To set _WIN32_WINNT in your source file, use the following statement:
>
> ```
> #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502
> ```
>
> To set _WIN32_WINNT using the /D compiler option, use the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> cl -c /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0502 source.cpp
> ```
>
> For information on using the /D compiler option, see /D (preprocessor
>   definitions).