# portable code between windows and linux

Tags: c++

I have an aplication written for linux,and i want to make it to execute under windows too. So how can i make a specific line in code to execute only if the programs runs under windows ? I know its somehting with #ifdef... Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
    // Your Windows specific code here
#endif
```

Edit based on comment:

There is a good discussion of _WIN32 vs WIN32 here: [Whats the difference between the win32 defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662084/whats-the-difference-between-the-win32-and-win32-defines-in-c)

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx you need a leading underscore.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the code. You might be able to just re-compile it and go. If not, the effort involved in porting may be trivial (a few minor details here or there) or it might be next to impossible (e.g., trying to port valgrind).

Before you jump into using `#ifdef`, read [Henry Spencer's paper](http://doc.cat-v.org/henry_spencer/ifdef_considered_harmful) on the subject.

Comment: i am suing sockets so for windwos i need to execute the part with WSAData crap :)

Comment: @vBx: *Most* sockets code is pretty trivial to port from Linux to Windows. The main things you need to change are adding calls to `WSAStartup` and `WSACleanup`. I'd generally keep those separate from the other code, and add a call to an `init` and `cleanup`. Keep the empty Linux versions of those in another file, and in the *makefile* select which one to compile into the application.

Comment: yes,thats how i did,and i need to test when i am in windows to call init and cleanup

Comment: @vBx: no -- my point is to *always* call init and cleanup -- but for Linux implement those as empty functions. Keep the Windows and Linux implementations in separate files, and have the makefile decide which gets used.

Comment: +1: That is a nice reference. Its surprising how the words written 20 years ago are still relevant today.

Answer (score 0):

I use `#ifdef _MSC_VER` to know if it's a Microsoft compiler, but I'm sure there are other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `#ifdef _WIN32`, but `#ifdef WIN32` also works.