# Is there a #define for 64 bit in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, 64-bit

Is there a #define that indicates whether Visual Studio is compiling in 64bit mode? I'd like to be able to include some code conditionally like so

```
#ifdef _IS_64BIT
  ...
#else //32 bit
  ...
#endif
```

I know I can create a flag myself, but I'm wondering if the compiler provides one.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
#ifdef _WIN64
  ...
#else
  ...
#endif
```

Documented on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170#microsoft-specific-predefined-macros)

Comment: Why in new Win32 C++ project WIN32 is defined, not _WIN32?

Comment: Just found brilliant answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/a/662543/13441

Comment: doc link is broken .. maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019 ? still this is the correct answer

Answer (score 9):

Use `_WIN64`. It won't matter the type of 64 bit processor.

Comment: Is there a define that only exists on x86_64? Or maybe this can be combined with a define that only exists on x86?

Answer (score 4):

`#ifdef WIN32` or `#ifdef _WIN32` will work in x64.

Comment: When does this appear? On any Windows? On 32-bit and 64-bit? On x86 and ARM?