# MinGW not defining WIN32, error in preprocessor directives

Tags: c, mingw, c-preprocessor

I am using mingw32-make to compile a project to Windows, which depends on a project called libevent2. I keep receiving this error -

```
util.h:69:25: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
```

Obviously a file from the Linux API is trying to be included, which won't work on Windows. Upon further investigation I find however that this file should only be included if **WIN32 isn't defined.**

```
#ifdef WIN32
 #include <winsock2.h>
#else
 #include <sys/socket.h>
#endif
```

Comment: "Your project"? Ensure WIN32 is defined. '<sys/socket.h>` requires cygwin, not just mingw32.

Comment: @John Sorry, 'a project'. What do you mean 'ensure WIN32 is defined?'.

Comment: What version of MinGW are you using?  What's the command line invoking the compiler?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use `_WIN32` and may also want to check for `__CYGWIN__`

```
#if defined _WIN32 || defined __CYGWIN__
```

Answer (score 13):

Are you sure there's nothing undefining `WIN32`?  My installation of MinGW (4.6.1 at this site) definitely defines it:

```
C:\temp>gcc -E -dM test.c | find /i "win"
#define _WIN32 1
#define __WINT_MAX__ 65535
#define _WINT_T
#define __WINT_MIN__ 0
#define __WIN32 1
#define __WINNT 1
#define __WINNT__ 1
#define __WIN32__ 1
#define __SIZEOF_WINT_T__ 2
#define WIN32 1                 // <-- right here
#define __WINT_TYPE__ short unsigned int
#define WINNT 1
```

Try passing the `-E -dM` options to verify if your MinGW compiler is (or isn't) pre-defining the `WIN32` macro.

Note that strictly speaking, `WIN32` should *not* be predefined by the compiler (since it's in the user's namespace) - only `_WIN32` should.  `WIN32` should be set by the SDK being used and/or by the build environment - that's the way it works in Microsoft's compilers.

For example, there's the following sequence in `windef.h`"

```
#ifndef WIN32
#define WIN32
#endif
```

and `/D "WIN32"` is put into Visual Studio C++ projects by default.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/662543/12711 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**GCC** does not define `WIN32` on Windows when it compiles based on a C++ standard, such as `-std=c++11` or other year. However, `_WIN32` is defined. When GNU extensions are enabled, which is normally the default or when specific GNU extensions are enabled with `-std=gnu++??`, then `WIN32` is defined together with `_WIN32`. 
 Use `_WIN32` instead of `WIN32` when possible. When it is impractical to replace it, either use the default GNU extensions without any switch or specific year with `-std=gnu++??` or define this macro in your build system. E.g. in the Makefile:

```
> ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
>     CXXFLAGS += -DWIN32
> endif
```