# Compiling C on Windows with gcc ... -lWs2_32

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, c-preprocessor

I am wanting to compile c through the command prompt on Windows.

I have the following file `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32

int main () {
    printf("Windows\n");
    return 0;
}

#else

int main () {
    printf("*nix\n");
    return 0;
}

#endif
```

And I follow these steps:

1. open cmd
2. `$ gcc -o testprog.exe main.c -lWs2_32`
3. `$ testprog.exe`

Output is `*nix`

I have installed MinGW and setup the path to `gcc`. I have also tried using `__MINGW32__`. What do I need to do?

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025708/mingw-not-defining-win32-error-in-preprocessor-directives#9026009

Comment: It works just fine on MSYS2.

Comment: What versions of the tools are you using?

Comment: What's the output of `g++ --version` (verbatim)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `g++ (GCC) 7.3.0`