# Preprocessor directives and #error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, c-preprocessor

I want to show error when someone try to compile my code under other system than WIN32 and LINUX. But this code:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    // Some code here for windows
#elif LINUX
    // Some code for linux
#else
#error OS unsupported!
#endif
```

But this gives me an error:

> #error OS unsupported

and compiler doesn't say anything else, just error.
What is wrong?

Comment: I'd say that `WIN32` is not defined, and `LINUX` either isn't defined or is zero.

Comment: Are you compiling on iOS?

Comment: @JonathanWakely it's doesn't matter
LuchianGrigore no, on Debian 7

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't matter?  `LINUX` is not defined on Linux, so testing for it is pointless. OTOH `__linux` is defined automatically.

Comment: Should you check for `_WIN32` in preference to `WIN32`?  According to http://stackoverflow.com/q/662084/311966 only `_WIN32` is guaranteed to be defined in the absense of system includes.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues here:

- your `#elif` does not test for the mere existence of the symbol, but for its truth (ie. defined *and* non-zero). You should use `#elif defined(...)` and, to be consistent, `#if defined(...)` at the start.
- the symbols you are matching for are wrong. You should use, respectively, `_WIN32` and `__linux__`. See [this reference](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/) for more platforms.

Answer (score 1):

`LINUX` is not a standard predefined macro. You probably want to check for `__linux` not `LINUX`

I know some code checks for `_WIN32` but I don't know what's correct on Windows.

Comment: `__linux` seems to be obsolete (not POSIX compliant) even though it works fine. Apparently one should use `__linux__` instead.

Comment: I think that reference is wrong, `linux` is not in the reserved namespace, but `__linux` is, so I don't know why it's not POSIX compliant. `__linux__` will certainly work too, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System_002dspecific-Predefined-Macros.html for more

Comment: "With the exception of identifiers beginning with the prefix `_POSIX_`, all identifiers that begin with an <underscore> and either an uppercase letter or another <underscore> are always reserved for any use by the implementation." http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html

Comment: Ah, I was looking for that too, except *you* actually managed to find it. ;) So yeah, `__linux` seems to be perfectly acceptable in the POSIX sense, indeed. No idea why my link says it's obsolete. My apologies. :)